# Assembly-CSharp.csproj error and Intellisense not working in VSCode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I recently started trying to learn how to use Unity, but the Unity Intellisense is not working for me whenever I try to write scripts in VSCode. Whenever I load the files in VSCode, a small notif appears in the corner saying that some projects have trouble loading. The terminal shows the following error: Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:file-path\project-name\Assembly-CSharp.csproj

I can still write and run code perfectly fine, but the Unity-related autocomplete terms don't show up which is going to screw me over since I'm very new to Unity.

I found this post where a user had the same problem, and the accepted solution was to "change the mono path to 'always' in the C# extension config". I tried doing that but I don't think I'm doing it right. I went to the extension settings and found an option called "Omnisharp: path" which has an "edit in json" link. Clicking the link took me to a settings.json file where I edited a value called omnisharp.monoPath to have the value "always". The json file now looks like this:

```
   "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "omnisharp.monoPath": "always",
    "omnisharp.path": ""
```

After saving, I was prompted to restart Omnisharp, but after doing so I still got the same "Attempted to update project that is not loaded" error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was? I'm facing the same problem, I tried looking here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/assembly-csharp-editor-csproj-could-not-be-loaded-because-it-doesnt-exist.529663/ and tried following it, but it still didn't help.

Comment: hi, i believe this video https://youtu.be/aorB7hzIOKM contained the solution that worked for me